# Position of 'not' in a negative interrogative?

Tags: questions, word-order, legalese, negation

[Source:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlill_v_Carbolic_Smoke_Ball_Co#Lord_Justice_Lindley) Carlill v Carbolic Smoke Ball Company [1892], judgement of Lindley LJ

> But there is another view. Does **not** the person who acts upon this advertisement and accepts the offer ♦  put himself to some inconvenience at the request of the defendants? Is it nothing to use this ball three times daily for two weeks according to the directions at the request of the advertiser? Is that to go for nothing?

I tried [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/114581). Am I right that this is a negative interrogative, and that Lindley LJ is just asking rhetorically: 'Does <s>not</s> the person .... put himself to some inconvenience ...'?

Why or why not should **not** be situated where I have inserted ♦ (ie the lozenge)?   What differs?

PS: [This Reddit post](https://redd.it/2oi12e) explicates this older syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key here is **Heavy Noun Phrase Shift**.  Here's how it works:

1. First, let's start with the canonical (declarative, affirmative) version:

   > *[The person who acts upon this advertisement and accepts the offer]*<sub>*subject*</sub> puts himself to some inconvenience at the request of the defendants.
2. Then we'll add the dummy auxiliary *do*.  We need this auxiliary for two reasons: to negate the predicate, and to mark the clause as interrogative through inversion:

   > *[The person who acts upon this advertisement and accepts the offer]*<sub>*subject*</sub> **does**<sub>*auxiliary*</sub> put himself to some inconvenience at the request of the defendants.
3. At this point, we can negate the predicate:

   > *[The person who acts upon this advertisement and accepts the offer]*<sub>*subject*</sub> **does**<sub>*auxiliary*</sub> **not**<sub>*negator*</sub> put himself to some inconvenience at the request of the defendants.
4. And now we can invert the subject and auxiliary, turning our declarative clause into an interrogative clause:

   > **Does**<sub>*auxiliary*</sub> *[the person who acts upon this advertisement and accepts the offer]*<sub>*subject*</sub> **not**<sub>*negator*</sub> put himself to some inconvenience at the request of the defendants?
5. Last, because our subject is so long and syntactical complex, and because this is particularly formal English, we can optionally make use of the rare **Heavy Noun Phrase Shift**, pushing our subject to the right out of its basic position, past the negator:

   > **Does**<sub>*auxiliary*</sub> **not**<sub>*negator*</sub> *[the person who acts upon this advertisement and accepts the offer]*<sub>*subject*</sub> put himself to some inconvenience at the request of the defendants?

When these conditions aren't met, we can't shift the subject noun phrase to the right:

> **Does**<sub>*auxiliary*</sub> *she*<sub>*subject*</sub> **not**<sub>*negator*</sub> like ice cream?
>
> ***Does**<sub>*auxiliary*</sub> **not**<sub>*negator*</sub> *she*<sub>*subject*</sub> like ice cream?　*(ungrammatical)*

The subject *she* isn't long or syntactically complex enough to count as as a "heavy" noun phrase, so it can't be shifted past the negator.

In contrast, the contracted form *doesn't* doesn't involve Heavy NP Shift; *-n't* is a [suffix](http://babel.ucsc.edu/%7Ehank/mrg.readings/ZPCliticsInfl.pdf), and so *doesn't* is a single word which inverts with a subject without any of these restrictions:

> *She*<sub>*subject*</sub> **doesn't**<sub>*negated-auxiliary*</sub> like ice cream.
>
> **Doesn't**<sub>*negated-auxiliary*</sub> *she*<sub>*subject*</sub> like ice cream?

For more discussion, see [my previous answer.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/19581/230)

Comment: +1. Thanks. Would you please clarify how *doesn't* differs? Based on your answer above, I'm guessing that the only difference relates to `Now the auxiliary is the single word *doesn't*, so if we apply subject-auxiliary inversion` in your other linked answer. In other words, the contracted *Doesn't ...?* only involves subject-auxiliary inversion and matches with *... does not*. Whereas *Does not...* above involves  Heavy Noun Phrase Shift?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit I updated my answer.

Comment: @snailboat Thank you effusively! I especially cherish your update because my comment and guess above look wrong!

Comment: I wonder whether it's preferable to use **doesn't** or **does not** before Heavy Noun Phrases, or they would be equal in sense.

Comment: @CopperKettle *Does not* is only possible in particularly formal style, usually in written English but occasionally in prepared speeches and the like.

Comment: Rhetorical 'gravity' (or some might say 'ponderousness') can allow the shift even if the subject isn't "heavy".

Answer (score -2):

It reminds me of the bit in *Merchant Of Venice*:

```
If you prick us, do we not bleed?
```

It seems to be hinting that the expected answer to the rhetorical question is the other way round - yes, we do.  Or in the court ruling - yes, the plaintiff did.

Comment: The quote you give has the "not" in pretty much the analogous position that the OP here is expecting, which is *not* where that word actually appeared in their passage, so this answer doesn't appear to explain anything about the word order, which is the only point of this question.